# How to append output of echo command in variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables

```
echo "string1"
echo "string2"
```

I want to write both echos in a variable, but I want the second echo to append on what is already written from the first, so that when I call it:

```
string1
string2
```

Also the output from the echos should be separated with new line.

Comment: is your sole purpose to append two strings with a linefeed?

Comment: Why do you want to involve `echo` in this rather than just `var='string1'; var="$var"$'\n''string2'` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand OP's requirement; if this is simply the appending of two strings with a linefeed ...

One idea using `printf -v`:

```
$ printf -v var "%s\n%s" "string1" "string2"

$ typeset -p var
declare -- var="string1
string2"

$ echo "${var}"
string1
string2
```

---

Or more simply:

```
$ var="string1"$'\n'"string2"

$ typeset -p var
declare -- var="string1
string2"

$ echo "${var}"
string1
string2
```

Comment: I thought the OP asked to save the output from a command, but if not, we can just write var="string1\nstring2" and be done with it.

Comment: @puravidaso to be honest I'm not sure what OP's asking for

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$( echo "string1"; echo "string2" )
```

Comment: That is very elegant (and I feel a bit stupid now). However, it depends on the first command issuing the newline character. For example, it will not work if echo is replaced by `echo -n`.

Comment: yes, technically, this is not inserting a newline between echos. but the question is rather unclear

Comment: I suggest: `var=$( echo "string1" | tr -d '\n'; echo; echo "string2" | tr -d '\n'; echo )`

Comment: @minorChaos : This argument is odd. If one explicitly writes `echo -n`, than he does it with the purpose that a newline is not wanted.

Comment: @user1934428 : Certainly he does not want to use this with echo command, but with some other program (certainly not `echo -n`, too). It may be a case when the other program does not issue the new line. (Most do, of course, but some do not -- everybody knows that echo is an example which sometimes does not, i.e. when having `-n` switch.)

Comment: @Cyrus: yes. That solves that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert a line-break (if you do not mind to distort the indentation):

```
   A="$(echo string1)
$(echo string2)"; 

   # test it now:
   echo -n "$A"|od -c
000000   s   t   r   i   n   g   1  \n   s   t   r   i   n   g   2
0000017
```

If you do not like breaking the indentation, the line-break becomes a precious thing. But there are ways how to get it:

```
# NL will contain line-break char
printf -v NL "\n"; 

# Or trick by inserting and removing X
NL="$(echo -e '\nX')"; NL="${NL/X}";

#test:
echo -n "$NL" | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001
  

# use it:
A="$(echo string1)$NL$(echo string2)"; 

# test it now:
echo -n "$A"|od -c
000000   s   t   r   i   n   g   1  \n   s   t   r   i   n   g   2
0000017
```

Or we can make it one-liner. Also I can `hexdump` instead of `od` for testing.

```
printf -v B "%s\n%s"  "$(echo string1)" "$(echo string2)"; 

echo "$B" | hexdump -C
00000000  73 74 72 69 6e 67 31 0a  73 74 72 69 6e 67 32 0a  |string1.string2.|
00000010
```

`-v B` means to store the result to variable `B` instead of printing it out.

`\n` needs no comment.

`%s` is like in `printf()` function in `C`, and the parameters are coming as parameters on the command line.  (Do NOT use `printf -v B "$(echo foo%%)$(echo bar%d)"` if you do not want to lose `%` etc. They have the place-holder function in the first parameter.)

Comment: Since the question is about bash: `NL=$'\n'` (Note that `-v` option to printf is not [portable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html))

Comment: Thanks. I think that was not possible 15 years ago.

Comment: With any POSIX shell you can do `NL='` <kbd>return</kbd> `'`

Comment: @jhnc: If   `NL='line-break'`  is POSIX compatible, is the same true for `NL="line-break"` ? (This is my first solution.)

Comment: [yes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02)

Answer (score -1):

```
a="${a:+$a\n}$(echo "string1")"
a="${a:+$a\n}$(echo "string2")"
echo $a
```

It has features you can add and delete any strings and there won't have a new line before the first string.

Comment: I think you need `${a:+$a$'\n'}`. double-quotes are required for `echo` but not the assignments

Comment: @puravidaso: I think you should put `a=""` before the first line since you cannot assume `a` is unassigned.